# Changing number formats in strings

Tags: string-manipulation

Given this (simplified and much shorter than the real case) string:

```
s="The value is now 3.219209e3, it has grown by 1.06e01 in the last year"
```

I would like to change the format of the numbers from the "e" notation to plain numbers:

"The value is now 3219.209, it has grown by 10.6 in the last year"

I have tried variations with `StringReplace` to do this e.g.:

```
StringReplace[s, StringExpression[m : NumberString, "e", e : NumberString] :>(ToExpression[m]*10^ToExpression[e])]
```

Which returns a `StringExpression` instead of a `String`:

```
"The value is now " ~~ 3219.21 ~~ ", it has grown by " ~~ 10.6 ~~ " in the last year"
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, is there a way of changing the format of numbers in a string like this that returns a `String` instead of a `StringExpression`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ToString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html) to convert the numbers into their string representation, which can then be merged properly with the rest of the string:

```
s =  "The value is now 3.219209e3, it has grown by 1.06e01 in the last year";

StringReplace[s,
 m : NumberString ~~ "e" ~~ e : NumberString :>
  ToString[ToExpression[m]*10^ToExpression[e]]
 ]
(* "The value is now 3219.21, it has grown by 10.6 in the last year" *)
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukas, a neat solution

Answer (score 3):

Using the functionality provided by `RegularExpression` along with `Interpreter`:

```
s = "The value is now 3.219209e3, it has grown by 1.06e01 in the last year"

nums = StringCases[s, 
  RegularExpression["[-+]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"]
  ]
```

> {"3.219209e3", "1.06e01"}

```
rule = Thread[Rule[nums, ToString@Interpreter["Number"][#] & /@ nums]]

{"3.219209e3" -> "3219.21", "1.06e01" -> "10.6"}

StringReplace[s, rule]
```

---

This above can be written succinctly as:

```
StringReplace[s, 
 k : RegularExpression["[-+]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"]
  :> ToString@Interpreter["Number"][k]]
```

---

Result:

> "The value is now 3219.21, it has grown by 10.6 in the last year"